# distributed Tensorflow tracking timestamps for synchronization operations

Tags: multithreading, machine-learning, tensorflow, synchronization, distributed

I am new to TensorFlow. Currently, I am trying to evaluate the performance of distributed TensorFlow using `Inception` model provided by TensorFlow team.

The thing I want is to generate timestamps for some critical operations in a Parameter Server - Worker architecture, so I can measure the bottleneck (the network lag due to parameter transfer/synchronization or parameter computation cost) on replicas for one iteration (batch).

I came up with the idea of adding a customized dummy `py_func` operator designated of printing timestamps inside `inception_distributed_train.py`, with some control dependencies. Here are some pieces of code that I added:

```
def timer(s):
  print ("-------- thread ID ", threading.current_thread().ident, ", ---- Process ID ----- ", getpid(), " ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ", s, datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
  return Falsedf

dummy1 = tf.py_func(timer, ["got gradients, before dequeues token  "], tf.bool)
dummy2 = tf.py_func(timer, ["finished dequeueing the token         "], tf.bool)
```

I modified

```
apply_gradients_op = opt.apply_gradients(grads, global_step=global_step)
with tf.control_dependencies([apply_gradients_op]):
  train_op = tf.identity(total_loss, name='train_op')
```

into

```
with tf.control_dependencies([dummy1]):
    apply_gradients_op = opt.apply_gradients(grads, global_step=global_step)
    with tf.control_dependencies([apply_gradients_op]):
      with tf.control_dependencies([dummy2]):
        train_op = tf.identity(total_loss, name='train_op')
```

hoping to print the timestamps before evaluating the `apply_gradient_op` and after finishing evaluating the `apply_gradient_op` by enforcing node dependencies.

I did similar things inside `sync_replicas_optimizer.apply_gradients`, by adding two dummy print nodes before and after `update_op`:

```
        dummy1 = py_func(timer, ["---------- before update_op   "], tf_bool)
        dummy2 = py_func(timer, ["---------- finished update_op "], tf_bool)

        # sync_op will be assigned to the same device as the global step.
        with ops.device(global_step.device), ops.name_scope(""):
            with ops.control_dependencies([dummy1]):
                update_op = self._opt.apply_gradients(aggregated_grads_and_vars, global_step)

        # Clear all the gradients queues in case there are stale gradients.
        clear_queue_ops = []
        with ops.control_dependencies([update_op]):
            with ops.control_dependencies([dummy2]):
                for queue, dev in self._one_element_queue_list:
                    with ops.device(dev):
                        stale_grads = queue.dequeue_many(queue.size())
                        clear_queue_ops.append(stale_grads)
```

I understand that `apply_gradient_op` is the `train_op` returned by `sync_replicas_optimizer.apply_gradient`. And `apply_gradient_op` is the op to dequeue a token (`global_step`) from `sync_queue` managed by the chief worker using `chief_queue_runner`, so that replica can exit current batch and start a new batch.

In theory, `apply_gradient_op` should take some time as replica has to wait before it can dequeue the token (`global_step`) from `sync_queue`, but the print result for one replica I got, such as the time differences for executing apply_gradient_op is pretty short (~1/1000 sec) and sometimes the print output is indeterministic (especially for chief worker). Here is a snippet of the output on the workers (I am running 2 workers and 1 PS):

[chief worker (worker 0) output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHbG7.png)

[worker 1 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsTkI.png)

> My questions are:
>
> 1) I need to record the time TensorFlow takes to execute an `op` (such as `train_op`, `apply_gradients_op`, `compute_gradients_op`, etc.)
>
> 2) Is this the right direction to go, given my ultimate goal is to record the elapsed time for executing certain operations (such as the difference between the time a replica finishes computing gradients and the time it gets the `global_step` from `sync_token`)?
>
> 3) If this is not the way it should go, please guide me with some insights about the possible ways I could achieve my ultimate goal.
>
> Thank you so much for reading my long long posts. as I have spent weeks working on this!

Comment: Have you considered using the `Timeline` class to collect information about the execution of your graph? There is some documentation on it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/tensorflow/3850/measure-the-execution-time-of-individual-operations#t=201703101913142622855). This will provide more information than you probably need, but it will show you the start time, end time, and duration of all of the ops (and related activities like GPU kernel executions).

Comment: @mrry Thank you Derek! This helps! :) As expected, the dequeue operation (synchronization point) takes much longer time.